# HTTP Post request with tab delimited parameter

Tags: http, httprequest

How can I read the data if I am getting the request in below format using a HTTP POST request:

`accountRequest=<NewUser>
userName password fName lName
ABC123 wzbtw88g Joe Bloggs
</NewUser>`

Comment: That doesn't seem related to Spring at all, you need to build some kind of whitespace delimited parser

Comment: @gerrytan you mean to say this type of request we cannot get in the request

Comment: I'm very curious how that format came into existence. Anyhow, did you try just reading the request parameter like any other?

Comment: @Bart thats the good point how this format came into existence, i will try to read that as considering that like String parameter.